How does this answer regarding vector arithmetic over word embeddings make sense?
I would like an explanation of the linear algebraic rational behind this answer, especially the idea that "The literal position of that vector maybe garbage because by checking it in the euclidean space, you will anchor it on the origin."
I get that vectors are ordinarily anchored on the origin, while vector addition geometry depicts them anchored at the tips of other vectors, but surely the only way $\vec{Queen} - \vec{Woman} ≈ \vec{King} - \vec{Man}$ and $\vec{Queen} - \vec{King} ≈ \vec{Woman} - \vec{Man}$ is if $\vec{Queen} - \vec{Women}$, etc., are near $\vec{Royal}$ or some similar words, and $\vec{Woman} - \vec{Man}$, etc., are near some gender toggling words.  As no coordinates are even depicted in the answer, it should be evident that this holds invariant of the choice of basis.
To me this claim sounds like the claim that "$7 - 5 = 4 - 2$, but the output $7 - 5$ and $4 - 2$ independently are meaningless because they express a distance from the origin."  How does this make sense within vector spaces?

I'm not familiar with the ins and outs of this algorithm, but from what I can tell, while the displacement between "Queen" and "Woman" may be similar to "King" from "Man", this displacement vector itself measures the displacement from the origin to (roughly) the word that's produced. You should ask, what word is represented by the origin (or what word is nearest to it)? It may not be as "neutral" as you might implicitly think; it's not like adding "royalty" to nothing to produce "royalty". Adding the concept of "royalty" to this word may not produce something sensible.

Its fairly straightforward to understand the difference. In the answer you have referenced it is the case that $\def\vb#1{\mathbf{#1}}$$\def\rm#1{\mathsf{#1}}$ $\vb{x}(\rm{King})-\vb{x}(\rm{Man})=\vb{x}(\rm{Queen})-\vb{x}(\rm{Woman})=\vb{x}(\rm{Something})$. But then the vector $\vb{x}(\rm{Something})$  in the embedding space will correspond to something that has nothing to do with what the equivalence vector is indicating (with a high probability it will correspond to gibberish; if the encdoing has bugs it may correspond to a word that has nothing to do with "same-sex").
